Joomla 4 custom template menu bad behaviour
I'm currently working on upgrading an e-commerce website from Joomla 3.x to 4.x.
The owner of the website want to use his own template, made for Joomla 4 that replicate the old template from joomla 3.
The issue is that the horizontal menu was configured to show the submenu on the mouse hover, like in the original website (www.cellafrigo.com).
In the Joomla 4 version of the website (this), the hovering works on the first level, but if I try to open the second level of submenu they are under the first layer and I can't find a way to show them in the foreground.


The template is made with TemplateToaster, and inside the application it's working ok, but when exported and installed on the live website it's not working properly.
